# Device firmware update and libusbx API in Windows CE

Tags: c, usb, windows-ce, libusb, firmware

I am trying to update the firmware on an Atmel device from a [Windows CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE) environment. Here is snippet of my source code:

```
uint8_t buf[127];
struct libusb_device_handle *handle=NULL;
fp = fopen("\\Nandflash\\a.hex", "r+");
size_t re = fread(buf, 4, 1, fp);
cstatus = libusb_control_transfer(
            handle, 
            LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT|
              LIBUSB_REQUEST_TYPE_VENDOR|
              LIBUSB_RECIPIENT_INTERFACE,
            0xA0, //Upload
            0x01, //Address of the device
            0,buf, sizeof(buf), 100);
```

I am keep getting `-9` as result of the control transfer. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a NULL handle value in your libusb_control_transfer function. You will need to initialize libusb and open the device to be able to talk to it:

```
uint8_t buf[127];
struct libusb_device_handle *handle=NULL;
struct libusb_context *context;
libusb_device **list;
libusb_device *found = NULL;

// Init libusb
libusb_init(&context);

// Open device your device
ssize_t cnt = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &list);
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    libusb_device *device = list[i];
    if (is_my_device(device)) {
        found = device;
        break;
    }
}

// If your device is found, open it and perform transfer, then close
if (found) {
    err = libusb_open(found, &handle);
    if (!err) {
        fp=fopen("\\Nandflash\\a.hex", "r+"); 
        size_t re=fread(buf, 4, 1, fp);
        cstatus=libusb_control_transfer(handle, LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_OUT|LIBUSB_REQUEST_TYPE_VENDOR|LIBUSB_RECIPIENT_INTERFACE,
           0xA0,//upload
           0x01, //address of device
           0,buf, sizeof(buf), 100);
        libusb_close(handle);
    }
}

// Cleanup
libusb_free_device_list(list, 1);
libusb_exit(context);
```

Comment: could you enlighten me with what should be the function is_my_device

Comment: You will probably want to do some matching on your VID and PID to ensure you know what you are talking to. Anything more depends on your implementation.

Comment: I tried  r=libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc); compare the desc vid and pid with known vid and pid.  I also tried get the handle through devh = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, 0x05ba, 0x000a);   I am still getting -9.   am I passing the correct parameter to the libusb_control_transfer? what the values are the fourth and fifth supposedly be?

Comment: When you make the call for `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid()` do you get a valid handle returned, and does the function succeed? If you don't have a valid device handle nothing will work. If you mean the fourth and fifth parameters of `libusb_control_transfer()` they are the wValue and wIndex values. You need to consult the protocol for your device to ensure these are valid, otherwise your device will NAK.

Comment: Yes I did get the valid handle

Comment: Then your next step is to validate that the control request you are sending to your device is valid. I'd recommend using a hardware analyzer as well, to see if you control request makes it out of the host or not.

Comment: it looks like the root of the problem is there may be a conflict between the  ceusbkwrapper driver and my hid driver.  I just found out that at image boot up, whenever the cewrapper driver is enable,  my hid driver just can not be initialized.  All the parameters that I get from cewrapper driver are all correct,  I just cannot send any data through HID.   is there any regedit value that I need to set for the hid interface for the cewrapper driver?

Comment: It looks like My hid driver can not find the slave device in the DFU mode.  What I need to do on the hid driver side to make it see the slave device?

Comment: DFU is not HID, and won't work with the HID driver. You'll need to communicate with it through libusb. I don't have a good grasp on what you are doing here, or what your system looks like. Once you enter DFU mode you should have access to open the device. You might update your question to be more concise if you need further assistance.

Comment: to resolve the problem that I have encountered, I need to Add a key to HKLM \Drivers\USB\ClientDrivers\Usb_Kernel_Wrapper 
defining a HID interface filter. This will tell ceusbkwrapper to always  automatically detach from the specified interfaces.      "InterfaceFilter_HID"        = "3:*:*"

Comment: that key resolved my earlier problem.   is there any way I can reattach the ceusbwrapper driver?

Comment: after I got into the DFU mode,  I am getting zero value from the function libusb_get_device_list(context, &list).